# Batch to insert a number in an existing string of numbers

Tags: batch-file, text, insert, numbers, document

I need to write a batch to insert the number "0" after the "5" in the string "12345678910"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If at all possible, it would be of great help if one could explain each line and/or command so that I can understand how the script works.

***EDIT***

Perhaps i should be more specific as I am reading these other articles. I need the script to **insert** the number "0" after the "5" in the string "12345678910" inside of a text document. In other words, i need to find any instance of "12345678910" in a given text file and then add a "0" after the "5" in each instance. So I need to edit an existing text document

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far...

Comment: waht can we use? bash? perl? awk? php?

Comment: Thank you. We are creating a .BAT file to be run via CMD. I have tried nothing as I have insufficient information to form a cogent script at this time - I am currently only researching.

Comment: [This page](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) has plenty of string manipulation examples that work.  Please write some code and **ask a question if you have a problem**.  Do not ask us to solve a problem without trying first yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quite easy.

```
(Read every line, 
  replace "12345678910" with "123450678910" 
  and write it out
) and put it in a new file
```

the Code:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (MyFile.txt) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    echo !line:12345678910=123450678910!
  )
)>newfile.txt
```

Reference: `for /?`, `set /?`

Comment: WICKED cool. Thank you so much for your time and effort! See, the problem with adhering to forum expectations is that i had no script to go off of. I didnt even know where to start. Thank you very much for helping me to learn!

Comment: @ChristopherMoore usually I tend not to answer questions, that look like "do my work for me", but I know, it's not easy to get a good start for doing something if you have no idea, what can be done. If you are new to scripting, you should consider to learn powershell instead of cmd (or as an optimum both of them). Powershell is a mighty designed language, where cmd slowly evolved through the last 25 years with emphasis to backward compatibility. There are a few minor things, where cmd is better, but as a rule, powershell has _much_ more power.

Answer (score 0):

use [variable search/replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) or [variable substring](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

example:

```
set "var=12345678910"

rem :: example with search/replace
echo %var:5=50%
:: output: 123450678910

rem :: example with variable substring
echo %var:~0,5%0%var:~5%
:: output: 123450678910
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. Perhaps i should be more specific as I am reading these other articles. I need the script to insert the number "0" after the "5" in the string "12345678910" inside of a text document. In other words, i need to find any instance of "12345678910" in a given text file and then add a "0" after the "5" in each instance. So I need to edit an existing text document.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore: Well, there is a _huge difference_ between "insert a number in an existing string" vs. "edit an existing text document". If you are not aware of this difference, then any further explanation have no sense... **`:(`**

Comment: @Aacini Well, I do apologize for the confusion. However, I feel that my ignorance of the _huge difference_ would be a perfect reason for further explanation. It is in my experience, that when someone is unaware of something and seeking to learn, further explanation is often required in order to make said individual aware and to teach them. I humbly request further patience and assistance with regards to my scripting. Thank you so much for your time, and I again apologize for my ignorance.